# Cannot setup Ionic monitoring with ionic cordova build --prod

Tags: ionic2, ionic-view

I tried the following command to try add the monitoring feature of ionic to diagnose a problem in my app using ionic view.

```
$ ionic monitoring syncmaps
```

> git rev-parse HEAD
>     √ Running command - done!
>    [INFO] No sourcemaps found, doing build...

```
? Do full prod build? (Y/n) y ?
```

> Do full prod build? Yes
>   [INFO] Running app-scripts build: --prod
>
> [22:16:31]  build prod started ...
>   [22:16:31]  clean started ...
>   [22:16:31]  clean finished in 1 ms
>   [22:16:31]  copy started ...
>   [22:16:31]  ngc started ...
>   [22:16:37]  ngc finished in 6.08 s
>   [22:16:37]  preprocess started ...
>   [22:16:37]  deeplinks started ...
>   [22:16:38]  deeplinks finished in 441 ms
>   [22:16:38]  optimization started ...
>   [22:16:38]  copy finished in 6.63 s
>   Error: ./src/pages/admin/admin.ngfactory.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../angularfire2/auth' in >'C:\Users\Gavin\Desktop\Web Development\app\src\pages\admin'
>   resolve '../../../angularfire2/auth' in 'C:\Users\Gavin\Desktop\Web Development\app\src\pages\admin' using description file: C:\Users\Gavin\Desktop\Web Development\app\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/admin)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

This error keeps going down the page for a long time, I get the same error if I type
    ionic cordova build --prod

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by deleting .ngmodules folder, downgrading my firebase version to npm i --save angularfire2@4.0.0-rc.1 , and then npm install. I was then able to build my app with ionic cordova --prod